# Rails: How to handle "Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a String" error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, string, activerecord, serialization

I have a table with one column that is of text type. 
There's a small string in it that should be serialized as an array

```
serialize :image_urls, Array
```

There are times when SQL is just faster for inserting data. 
When this is the case, I do the insert as a string

```
["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg"]
```

Since I'm inserting a string my Rails app crashes when it tries to read the data, with the following error message:

```
Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a String
```

**Is there a way to not have this error thrown, or to catch it and convert the data?**

I mean converting the string to an array is just a simple call, so, this should be easy.  I just don't know where, or how to accomplish it.

---

I sort of think overriding object_from_yaml, but I'm not sure where to do this work. 

Am I in the right track?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize):

> **serialize**`(attr_name, class_name = Object)`
>   [...] The serialization is done through YAML.

So the column should contain a YAMLized version of your `image_urls` but `'["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg"]'` is not a YAML array. If you want to muck around with the raw serialized data then you should use something like

```
["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg"].to_yaml
# ---------------------------^^^^^^^
```

to generate the string.

Or better, stop using `serialize` altogether in favor of a separate table.

Comment: The data is too complex to normalize.. Or well it would be a right pain, because I'd have to have dozens of really little tables (this example is with one field, but there are quite a few in the table)

Comment: Is there a way to override the function that is throwing the error?

Comment: @dave: Fix the data in your database: you broke it, you bought it.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 4 it worked for me without any `.to_yaml`, just added it to strong params as `image_urls: []`

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this: {:serialized_attribute_name => [ ]}. And don't forget to add this in appropriate controller as strong parameters.  It helps me when I was suffering from same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a 'serialized' array column, I have found this to be extremely helpful. Adding this to the migration for the column you wish to have as an array:

```rb
add_column :table, :column_name, :text, array: true, default: '{}', using: "(string_to_array(column_name, ','))"
```

With this, you don't need to 'serialize' the column. It will be an array.

Comment: Have you tested this with MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Comment: I had used it in a Rails app with a PostgreSQL db