# Attribute was supposed to be an Array, but was a String

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a text field in my database serialized to an array:

```
class EmailMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :from, Array
```

Before saving the ActiveRecord object, I assign a value to the method:

```
@email_message.from = [current_user.email]
```

But object does not save. Instead I get an error:

```
Attribute was supposed to be an Array, but was a String. -- "user@gmail.com"
```

Why is this error happening? I thought I passed an array to the method. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails How to handle :Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273301/rails-how-to-handle-attribute-was-supposed-to-be-a-array-but-was-a-string)

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `to_yaml`:

```
@email_message.from = [current_user.email].to_yaml
```

Also, if you haven't already, add `from: []` to your strong parameters.

This is a common oversight sometimes.