# How to Store String Array via ActiveAdmin in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have a model with an attribute that stores array into the database. Here's what it looks like:

```
// It has over 5 fields but the field tags is a string array. All others are just strings.

class JobPost < ApplicationRecord
    serialize :tags, Array
end
```

When I try to update the database via rails console everything works fine. But when I try to  update the database via ActiveAdmin I am getting the following error:

> ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch in Admin::JobPostsController#create
> can't serialize `tags`: was supposed to be a Array, but was a String. -- "tag"

Following is my ActiveAdmin file:

```
ActiveAdmin.register JobPost do
  permit_params :title, :location, :companyname, :tags, :applyurl
end
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273301/rails-how-to-handle-attribute-was-supposed-to-be-a-array-but-was-a-string-er

Comment: No. I am using sqlite3 in development. It's a string.